# How to post form within one page without use HttpResponseRedirect() in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a simple blog application, I used HttpResponseRedirect() to redirect to the blog detail after users commented like this
`return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('detail', args=(in_blog_id)))`
but when I click the back button in my browser, it would turn to the page before submit comment, I mean, the page have the comment form fulfilling, I just want users turn back to the blog list when they click back button after commenting.
So does it have a function or a way in Django to do it?
I'm sorry I didn't make it clear above, I mean I just want to post form within one page, I'm using a `CommentView()` and make a `url()` direct to this view,

```
<form action="/blogs/{{ blog.id }}/comment/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>Name:</label><input type="text" name="author"/>
    <label>Comment:</label><input type="text" name="comment_text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

use this code in my html file to make a form. When I click submit it would turn to     `/blogs/{{ blog.id }}/comment/` and then I use `HttpResponseRedirect()` to turn back.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the browser history with Django...but you can with javascript. You should look into the [javascript history api](http://html5doctor.com/history-api/).

[This is a nice guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) from Mozilla.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, meshy. I mean maybe it's a way not using `HttpResponseRedirect()`. I use `CommentView()`  `url(r'^(?P<in_blog_id>\d+)/comment', views.CommentView, name = 'comment')` and then redirect to the previous page, can I use Javascript or just using django to post form without turn to other page?Just like I comment in your answer?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. You should look into AJAX.